# windows phone development, TextBlock binding to the pivot selectedindex

Tags: c#, binding, windows-phone-8, pivot, textblock

I have a question about data binding in `TextBlock`.
I'm using a `Pivot` control as a pager.  In each page, there's a `TextBlock` used to show the pagination.
I know I can do it like this.

```
List<customData> data;
myPivot.ItemTemplate = data;
```

I can create a property `index` in `customData`, and bind the `TextBlock.Text` to this index.  But I think there should be an easier way to realize this.  I just want to use the `TextBlock` to show the 1, 2, 3... page number.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: Why you need to show an index for pivot control? A lot of item will be break the windows phone guide line.
But you can get selectedIndex with the selectionChange Event.

Comment: {Binding SelectedIndex,ElementName=pivot}

Comment: @MatDevWp8 Thank you so much.  It works, but I still have a question, by the Binding method, is it possible to show the page number from 1?  We know that the SelectedIndex is from 0.

Comment: You have to write a IValueConverter for that.

Comment: You can use the same property in a textblock et use a converter and just do "+1" at value?. Yes, it is a small strong but i don't see an other issue.